# In javascript, Is there a perfect way to define class

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I am looking for a perfect way to define class. "perfect" here means:`

1. create instances will not create copies of methods.
2. public function could easily(not to much hassle) access private variable

For example, way 1:

```
function Foo1() {
  var private1;
  this.publicMethod1 = function() {//create instance will create copy of this function}
}
```

will not meet rule No.1 above.

Another example, way 2:

```
 function Foo2() {
      var private2;

    }
 Foo2.prototype.Method2 = function() {//cannot access private2}
```

will not meet rule No.2 above.

So is it possible to meet both rules? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript it's more about conventions. Private properties or methods are defined with a underscore first like `_private`. With a few helpers you can make classes easily. I find this setup easy enough, all you need is a helper `inherits` to extend classes, and instead of using multiple arguments you pass in an object `props` and simply call "super" on the inherited classes with `arguments`. For example, using a module pattern:

```
Function.prototype.inherits = function(parent) {
  this.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
};

var Person = (function PersonClass() {

  function Person(props) {
    this.name = props.name || 'unnamed';
    this.age = props.age || 0;
  }

  Person.prototype = {
    say: function() {
      return 'My name is '+ this.name +'. I am '+ this.age +' years old.';
    }
  };

  return Person;

}());

var Student = (function StudentClass(_super) {

  Student.inherits(_super);      

  function Student(props) {
    _super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.grade = props.grade || 'untested';
  }

  Student.prototype.say = function() {
    return 'My grade is '+ this.grade +'.'; 
  };

  return Student;

}(Person));

var john = new Student({
  name: 'John',
  age: 25,
  grade: 'A+'
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(john)); //=> {"name":"John","age":25,"grade":"A+"}
console.log(john.say()); //=> "My grade is A+"
```

About the private variable "issue" just stick to convention for instance properties and use closures when needed for everything else private.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Foo3() {
    this.private = {};
}

Foo3.prototype.set_x = function (x) {
    this.private.x = x;
};
```

Comment: to be precise, in this case your field `private` is still public.

Comment: @Chips_100 Yes, but that wasn't part of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short: no, it is not. You cannot extend the prototype with methods that could access `private` variables. At least if these private variables are made private via a `closure`.

Though, it is a convention in javascript that you mark your private fields with an underscore, for example `_myPrivateField`. These would be still public, but i have seen this solution being used in many libraries and i also prefer that style to meet your first rule.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example is below:

```
Foo = function(id)
{
    // private instances.
    var _id;
    var _self = this;

    // constructor
    _id = id;

    // private method
    function _get()
    {
        return _id;
    };

    // public function
    _self.set = function(id)
    {
        _id = id;
    };
    _self.get = function()
    {
        return _get();
    };
};

var bar = Foo(100);
console.log( bar.get() );
bar.set(1000);
console.log( bar.get() );
```

I would recommend you use [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/).